# DNS look ups slow with mts blaze

Tags: 10.10, configuration, internet, dns

I am trying to use Mts mblaze on ubuntu 10.10. I am getting downloading speed of more than 100kb/sec but browsing is too slow as its taking too much time for dns look up. Google.com is working perfectly fine, but when i am trying to click on any search result i am getting same issue, too slow..

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Check out your pings with the web site you use to check to quality of your connection.

```
ping ip/host
```

If you are sure it's a DNS issue, then try these DNS:

```
4.2.2.2

4.2.2.1
```

Should perform faster than your ISP's DNS provider.

Answer (score 1):

You can test your dns speed with the dig command, ie:
`dig www.google.com`

If that is the problem, you can setup dns caching by installing resolvconf and a dns server (or cacher?), ie: `sudo apt-get install dnsmasq resolvconf`

There are other dns servers you can use, like bind9; I  think they are listed in the resolvconf package description.  I don't know what the difference is though.

Answer (score 0):

May be [this](http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/08/02/local-dns-cache-for-faster-browsing/) will help you?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with MTS's DNS servers, you could try using other DNS servers, such as [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/), [Google](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns) or [Scrubit](http://www.scrubit.com/).

If you hunt around you may find some open DNS servers in India which may have less latency being closer to you.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is with the DNS resolution. Most ISP's in INDIA ( Mine included) have poor resolution rates. I would suggest you to use the OpenDNS servers as they are not only fast but give you additional features like domain-blocking and shortcuts.

The IP Addresses are

208.67.222.222,
208.67.220.220

Let us know if you face any problem.